# Error: cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required)

Tags: c++

When I compiled the project using g++ it is working, but when it comes to visual studio it shows an error **Error: cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required)**

Code:

```
void Student::eat() {

    // Holds file data
    map< string, tuple<int, int, int, int> > data;

     for (const auto& entry : data)
    {

    }

}
```

I shorten the code, so I could point at the problem. I got an error at entry.

```
 for (const auto& entry : data)
```

Comment: check whether VS coompiler version supports C++11?

Comment: how do i do that? I'm new using VS software

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley 2010 version

Comment: That doesn't support range-based for loops. Any reason you can't get a newer version?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley my lecturer is using visual studio 2010, so I have no other choice.

Comment: Then you can't use this feature. You'll have to use a traditional for loop, or  the `std::for_each` algorithm.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley could you show the answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 does not support range-based for loops, it does support `auto` though, so you can do this:

```
for (auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
{
    ...
}
```

But note that with this, you have an iterator, as opposed to an element that you would have with a range-based for loop. So you need to dereference it, i.e. `i->first`, and `i->second`.